# "Sequence contains no elements" error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

Im getting the error "Sequence contains no elements" in a simple xaml form. 
I am fairly new to Xamarin forms so please bear with me.

Any thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CRM.Views.CustomerItem" Title="Customer Info">

<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
            <Entry Text="{Binding CustName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Surname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
            <Entry Text="{Binding CustSurname}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Address" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="PhoneNumber" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
            <Entry Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

    <Button Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" Clicked="Save_Clicked"></Button>
    <Button Text="Cancel" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked"></Button>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: your Buttons are not contained within any layout, and your Grid does not have any Rows defined

Answer (score 8):

Always make sure ContentPage.Content has only one layout control like StackLayout or Grid etc and all other controls inside them.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout>
       <!-- all controls go here -->
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

That will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are fine but the grid has no rows defined but you are using Grid.Row="0". As there are no rows in the Grid.Rows it says "Sequence contains no elements"

try adding row definition

```
<StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="100" />
             <RowDefinition Height="100" />
             <RowDefinition Height="100" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding CustName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Text="Surname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding CustSurname}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Text="Address" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Text="PhoneNumber" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>

<Button Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" Clicked="Save_Clicked"></Button>
<Button Text="Cancel" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You Must be Create Rows and Columns Both...

<Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632302/xamarin-forms-sequence-contains-no-elements#comment76250080_44632302) is right. There are multiple errors:

1. [`Content`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage.Content/) does only take one `View` element.

In this case this should be `StackLayout`. Your buttons *Save* and *Cancel* should be within the `StackLayout`.

2. Your `Grid` doesn't contain any `RowDefinition`.

If you had only one element and no row defined, this would work. Since you are explicitely using multiple rows, you need a [`RowDefiniton`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/#Rows_and_Columns) for that.

So in your case it should look like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CRM.Views.CustomerItem" Title="Customer Info">

<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding CustName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Label Text="Surname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding CustSurname}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Label Text="Address" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Label Text="PhoneNumber" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>

        <Button Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="Cancel" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for this is to include all your controls inside one panel.The below one will show how you will put.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Padding="40" Margin="0,80,0,0">
                <Label Text="UserName" TextColor="Black" ></Label>
                <Entry Text="" Placeholder="UserName" x:Name="username"></Entry>
                <Label Text="Password" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                <Entry Text="" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" ></Entry>
                <Button Text="Login" Clicked="Login_Clicked"></Button>
                <Label Text="Not a Member? sign up Now" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

If you put anything outside the stack panel will give you that errorr.